# How to make a player, without an interface, but with the ability to rewind in python?

Tags: python, audio-player

I have found many ways to interact with music in python, but in all there are only a few commands, start, stop, volume change, but I can't find a banal rewind.

The code at the moment:

```
import vlc
import time
import os
import random


def sound(sound):
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(sound)
    player.set_media(media) 
    player.play()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    time.sleep(duration)


path = r'C:\Hobby\Music'
files = os.listdir(path)
random.shuffle(files)

for i in files:
    print(sound(os.path.join(path, i)))
```

Comment: I remember one of my colleagues used pygame's audio functions for this exact same reason in one of our projects. Maybe take a look at those. It is not exactly a "rewind", it allows you to start the audio from a certain time if I remember correctly.

Comment: @MohamedYasser I can't find it in the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html), help.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pygame's mixer music. It is not exactly a rewind, but it allows you to start playing the audio from a certain time. Documentation [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html).